# (Error: Network Error) - Can't make a POST request from android simulator (Wifi is ON!)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I'm making a POST request to my own server and my server doesn't even receive any request (no request was shown in server terminal).

I can use an internet on browser inside of the simulator. But it's giving me the error below.

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:546)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:381)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:485
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:181)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:260)
    at MessageQueue.js:101
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:228)
```

And below is my POST request using axois

```
export const doAuthLogin = ({ username, password }) => async dispatch => {
  axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/rest-auth/login/`, {
    username,
    password
  }).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      // Save Token post is Already await. 
      AsyncStorage.setItem('auth_token', response.token);
      dispatch({ type: AUTH_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: response.token });
    })
    .catch(response => {
      console.log(response);
      dispatch({ type: AUTH_LOGIN_FAIL, payload: response.non_field_errors });
    });
};
```

What is Network Error? And how can I fix it?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Does your API in localhost?

Comment: yes. I am using Django RESTful Framework.

Comment: I don't show any request on server side terminal. :( it's very weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your `ROOT_URL` are you trying to do request to localhost? If it's the case try changing `ROOT_URL` to `10.0.2.2:YOUR_PORT`. Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html) for more information about android emulator and networking.

Comment: OMG. Holly crab you are right. I just got a request!

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. I lost a lot of time on this problem before I found the solution :) Can you accept my answer for other people who have the same problem?

Comment: yeap in 33 seconds

Answer (score 1):

If you put your API in localhost you can do the following steps.

1. Check your laptop IP by typing `ifconfig` (for ubuntu and mac) or `ipconfig` (for windows). For example you got `192.168.40.6`
2. Run your django for example`python manage.py runserver 192.168.40.6:8000`
3. Specifiy your axios url. For example

   axios.post(`http://192.168.40.6:8000/rest-auth/login/`, {...})
4. Make sure your phone connect to the same wifi with your laptop, and you can try the connection in your phone browser by go to `http://192.168.40.6:8000`

Comment: Sorry this is for pysical device

Comment: No problem. I'm sure I will use your instruction in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, as Hana said it's for physical device and [reactotron](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron) config if you want to debug your state when using real phone.